# Recursion - keep going

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

More than one basin submerges -

vassals take wrong end of ash for ships.

Wit and aspiration, alongside,

hold up to take supper at harbour -

pint (swallowed whole?) gives purpose.

Foremost three first (or four, we hear)

recorded observations a tad misplaced.

A success without us backing admission,

with race of batons racing depositor.

.

(5, 7, 4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 5)

.

> (4, 4, 3)

.

> (4)

Comment: This is a nice puzzle, but can I just add that after a day or two people will have lost interest so it would be better to add hints after a few hours (if no one has got the answer) when people are still viewing and its still at the top of the 'newest' list

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I thought an edit bumped the question back to the top? Does that not happen?

Comment: it bumps it to the top of the active list but not the newest list

Comment: @DeveloperInDevelopment, would you mind putting in word lengths? It's standard practice in cryptic clues.

Comment: @RichardRoe I couldn't think of a consistent way to do it without giving too much away... but I think I'll add them anyway.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil ... it doesn't make a difference whether the hints are added after a few hours or a few days, it *only* goes back to the top of the 'active' list, never to the top of the 'newest' list

Answer (score 7):

More than one basin submerges - (5)

> SINKS: double def

vassals take wrong end of ash for ships. (7)

> VESSELS (æ switch: solved by Richard)

Wit and aspiration, alongside, (4)

> WITH (aspirated "wit": thanks, M!)

hold up to take supper at harbour - (7)

> SUP + PORT

pint (swallowed whole?) gives purpose. (5)

> P[O]INT

Foremost three first (or four, we hear) (3)

> FOR(-emost), FOUR homophone (no definition????)

recorded observations a tad misplaced. (4)

> DATA* (thanks, Richard)

A success without us backing admission, (6)

> A[-su]CCESS (thanks, Richard (again))

with race of batons racing depositor. (5)

> LAYER* (or RELAY*) ("racing" indicates anagram - thanks, M!)

---

Put together, we get

> Sinks vessels with support point for data access layer (4,4,3)

Sinks vessels

> POTS  sinks(v) in billiards,vessels in cooking

(with) support point

> SPOT (double def: to "spot" in the military or in water sports is to watch out while someone else is occupied)

for data access layer

> 

Comment: "With and aspiration" is WITH (alongside). I think the last is LAYER, one who deposits; wordplay is anagram (racing) of RELAY (baton race). With all that computer terminology, I guess that the harbour is a PORT, but I have no clue on the wordplay.

Comment: @MOehm: Oh, never expected an indirect anagram.

Comment: ships can sometimes be referred to as vessels

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure it's right. As for the serfs: I guess they may "take the wrong end" and become SERVES, so that something can be inserted to make it services, servers or some such. (The "wrong end" would be the wrong plural form modelled on knives, shelves etc.) These words are no ships, though

Comment: @M: RELAY/LAYER seems right to me. And that "wrong end" thing seems promising too.

Comment: _These words are no ships, though._ Oh, they are! The "Service" is the Navy, of course.

Comment: @M: How would "ash" fit in though?

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't work anyway: It has to be SERV*ES, with an S. Never mind.

Comment: Line 2 is tricky. My compact dictionary wouldn't help, but a well known online dictionary is more use. You are right that line 6 has no definition, but it seemed relatively straightforward. The Ximenean principles are really all about fairness - you shouldn't feel clever for setting an unfair clue and then brag about how "hard" it is. With easier clues I think there is a little latitude to have a bit of fun.

Comment: Last one is probably relay, not layer. It is the "depositor" that is "racing" after all.

Comment: @RichardRoe sorry, "layer" is correct. It's "relay" "racing" to give "layer" - "one who lays", definition "depositor".

Comment: @Richard: You shouldn't use the surface reading to give you any clues about the cryptic reading - they're entirely separate. But for the next clue, "...access layer" makes more sense than "...access relay"

Comment: @DeveloperInDevelopment I see. I had it backwards.

Comment: I think "tubs" and "pans" work well for "vessels", but are poor fits for "sinks". I hope you'll find the correct answer more convincing.

Comment: @Deusovi Also [spotting in weightlifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotting_%28weight_training%29) is even more precisely support.

Comment: I think sinks vessels is subs. Its a vessel that sinks and it sinks other vessels.

Comment: @Tony: Have you done a cryptic clue before? They can be separated into two entirely different parts, with no interaction between them.

Comment: "sinks" and "vessels" don't really work as synonyms - they give two different senses of the first word of the solution. The Crucible may be one vessel to consider, but don't mistake the cue - this one takes balls... and pockets... and I've thrown subtlety to the wind here, but I'm trying to be sporting [wink]. For the rest, the "for" was meant to indicate the clue "[support point] for [data access layer]". You probably would have guessed this, getting stuck trying to solve the second half, but I admit you do seem to have made a valid double definition from "support point". That was unintended.

Comment: so, by that clue sinks vessels is "pots" ?

Comment: I'd love to see this answer completed... it's soooo cloooose.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like

> A three layer cryptic clue, judging by the word lengths given and the title.

The answers to some of the clues

Vassals take wrong end of ash for ships

> "Vessels" [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) "Ash" can refer to the oddly written AE stuck together, which can be better seen at the link. This means that "Vassals" taking the wrong end of "ash" (the e) can become "vessels", ships

Hold up to take supper at harbour

> "Support" = hold up, "sup" = take supper, "port" = harbour (thanks @andenthal)

Recorded observations a tad misplaced

> "Data" (recorded observations, anagram of "a tad")

A success without us backing admission

> "Access" (admission, "A success" without "us")

So all words together, (with those solved Deusovi and Oehm) make up the phrase:

> Sinks vessels with support point for data access layer

Which according to the hint should be a cryptic clue, the answer of which should be three words of 4 letters, 4 letters, and three letters

Comment: As for the "three layer thing", that's what it seemed like to me too.

Comment: good job on line 2 :)

Comment: Very good. So I was barking up the wrong ash entirely. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Mostly building on @Deusovi answer and comments. Please build off it.

Pretty sure the phrase should be similar to this (using currently known):

> Syncs servers with support point for data access layer.

Which will further describe:

> either a HW or SW networking/infrastructure device - I'm guessing.

Comment: Ha! I love "syncs"! Sadly, its wrong - but a lovely idea. I'd add an indicator such as "we hear" in that case, but I do like it.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure either, figure it couldn't hurt to throw it out there - maybe help someone else.

Comment: "support" has gotta be right anyway, it fits perfectly!

Comment: correct on line 4 :)